# What is the command to display disk usage of current directory?

Tags: disk-usage, command

Which command in Unix is used to display the disk usage of current directory?

Comment: have you done any research before you posted your question?

Comment: are you writing a school test?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
du -sh .
```

for current directory.